# Serialization problem when updating a JSON file in a Dataframe

Tags: json, scala, insert-update, databricks

I read in a **JSON** file and store it in a **Dataframe**.

```
val df1 = spark.read.option("multiline", "true")
            .json("dbfs:/something.json")
```

The **Schema** of this file looks like the following:

```
Connections:array
    element:struct
           Name:string
           Properties:struct
                   database:string
                   driver:string
                   hostname:string
                   password.encrypted:string
                   password.encrypted.keyARN:string
                   port:string
                   username:string
           Type:string
```

I would like to build a function that could be reused when I want to add a new connection.

I was not sure what is the best way to do that, should I build a new schema, fill it with data and append it to the original Connections array, and then simply write back to the file?

This is how I try to make it work, but there is an error with serialization.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StructField, IntegerType, StringType, ArrayType, FloatType}

val zipsSchema3 = StructType(List(
  StructField("Name", StringType, true), 
  StructField("Properties", StructType(List(
      StructField("driver", StringType, true), 
      StructField("hostname", StringType, true), 
      StructField("password.encrypted", StringType, true), 
      StructField("password.encrypted.keyARN", StringType, true), 
      StructField("port", StringType, true), 
      StructField("username", StringType, true)
 ))),
  StructField("Type", StringType, true)
))

val data2 = Seq(
  Row("db2", struct("test","testHost","encpwd","keyTest","testPort","testUser"), "typeTest"))

val df = spark.createDataFrame(
  spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data2),
  zipsSchema3
)
```

Or is there some built in functions that could be used in this case?

Thank you in advance for all your suggestions! :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure why but the serialization error went away when I ran it like this.

```
 val zipsSchema3 = StructType(List(
      StructField("Name", StringType, true), 
      StructField("Properties", StructType(List(
          StructField("driver", StringType, true), 
          StructField("hostname", StringType, true), 
          StructField("password.encrypted", StringType, true), 
          StructField("password.encrypted.keyARN", StringType, true), 
          StructField("port", StringType, true), 
          StructField("username", StringType, true)
     ))),
      StructField("Type", StringType, true)
    ))

val data2 = Seq(("db2", Seq("test","testHost","encpwd","keyTest","testPort","testUser"), "typeTest"))

val rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data2)
  .map{ case (name, props, sType) => Row(name, props, sType ) }

val df = spark.createDataFrame(
  rdd,
  zipsSchema3  
)
```

Comment: I did not get error running this code, but I cannot write the dataframe out with the data inside. I get this error: _Error while encoding: java.lang.RuntimeException: scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon is not a valid external type for schema of struct_

Comment: I mean for example df.show(), display(df), none of this wants to show me the result, otherwise it looks good. The same problem I had with my code, just different error message :)